# invalid mount config for type volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i want to update my docker-compose, dotnet configuration but after that, i get the follwing error msg after docker-compose up (with the old version of dotnet the solution worked well):

```
ERROR: for 4c115b1b9fef_4c115b1b9fef_identityServer  Cannot create container for service identityserver: invalid volume specification: '17fa9043120077131e36ea4de1c4a5232b571dd70b5584e9823794ad7a379de5:[“/app”]:rw': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '[“/app”]' mount path must be absolute

ERROR: for identityserver  Cannot create container for service identityserver: invalid volume specification: '17fa9043120077131e36ea4de1c4a5232b571dd70b5584e9823794ad7a379de5:[“/app”]:rw': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '[“/app”]' mount path must be absolute
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-sdk

#Install dockerize
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget

ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.4.0
RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz


WORKDIR /app
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
EXPOSE 5000
VOLUME [“/app”]

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  identityserver:
    build: ./IdentityServer/docker
    container_name: identityServer
    volumes:
      - ./IdentityServer/:/app/
    links:
      - hawai-dashboard-database:hawai-database
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMET=Development
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - hawai-dashboard-database
```

The only thing i have changed is the line at the dockerfile : FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk to FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-sdk

What can be the problem?

Comment: Remove line `VOLUME [“/app”]` from **Dockerfile**, you already defined volume in **docker-compose.yml**, so `/app` folder in your container will be your machine's `./IdentityServer` folder

Comment: i removed the line VOLUME [“/app”] from Dockerfile, but the error msg is the same

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: i switched to FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env